# Want to extract values from text file using regex

Tags: java, regex

```
"00.00.00.00" 00.00.00.00 - - [07/Jun/2016:00:00:00 -0700] "Hey /acd?bg=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "00.00.00.00:0000" "Java/1.8.0_66" - - 2000
```

There are records as above, i want to extract values from all the fields , each field is separated by space , please help

I am using as below:

```
String p;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

But I am not getting the correct output. I am new to regex
The desired out put is

```
00.00.00.00
00.00.00.00
-
-
07/Jun/2016:00:00:01 -0700
Hey /acd?bg=1 HTTP/1.1
200
```

Comment: Why did you include the javascript tag?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a pattern that does what you want, but it isn't pretty:

```
^"((?:\d\d?\d?\.){3}\d\d?\d?)" ((?:\d\d?\d?\.){3}\d\d?\d?) (-) (-) (\[\d\d\/\w+\/\d{4}(?::\d\d){3} -\d{4}\]) "(.*?)" (\d{3})
```

To break it down a bit (because it's nasty):

`^` makes it start at the beginning of the string.

`((?:\d\d?\d?\.){3}\d\d?\d?)` will match and capture the first IP address, with each element being composed of between 1 and 3 digits. The same pattern is then used to match the second IP address as well.

`(-)` will capture the hyphens - not sure why you want it, but it's in your desired input.

`(\[\d\d\/\w+\/\d{4}(?::\d\d){3} -\d{4}\])` captures the timestamp (the bit in the square brackets).

`"(.*?)"` will match and capture the text string.

Finally, `(\d{3})` will capture the HTTP status code.

Taken together, this pattern will match the stuff you want from the string you provided.